# Test with symfony2, error in charge entities

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, testing, phpunit

I have a unit test like this:

```
namespace My\WebBundle\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use My\WebBundle\Controller\SynMCController;
use My\WebBundle\Entity\Users;

class MyControllerTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
public function testFunction()
    {
        $user1 = new Users();
        ...
    }
}
```

But when I try to test it with PHP Unit, I get this error:

> Class 'My\WebBundle\Entity\Users;' not found in ...\MyControllerTest.php on line 13

Line 13 is:

```
$user1 = new Users();
```

¿What is the problem to use a Entity in my Test Case? Of course my entity Users is in this path, I have used this path in lots of classes.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Are you sure your entity is not called `User` instead of `Users`?

Comment: Thanks, but yes, is users with "s".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `phpunit.xml` file is well defined, especially the  `bootstrap` attribute. It should point to the
`app/bootstrap.php.cache` file which is in charge of using the right autoloader

```
require_once __DIR__.'/autoload.php';
```

Comment: Thanks, but other test are working fine, but is in this test where I used my entity users, and really the phpunit charge well the test because read the code and if I remove this entity works fine (but obvisuly I need this entity to test this case)